# Grey lines showing up on textured plane

Tags: three.js

I'm fairly new to three.js. I've been playing around with constructing a rough terrain object by manipulating the vertices of a plane. I also map its UVs to an atlas of square textures.

I'm running into an issue where I have grey lines going across the plane in one direction. I've seen similar problems mentioned before, some mentioning that it was a problem with the CanvasRenderer, and that `overdraw: true` was the appropriate fix. I am using the WebGL renderer (I tried `overdraw: true` anyways, but that didn't have any effect).

When I cut out my UV manipulation, the lines disappear. Below is the code I use to manipulate the UVs, where the `biomeTerrains[biome][#]` returns Vector2 values.

```
for (var y = 0;y < rowLength-1;y++) {
    for (var x = 0;x < rowLength-1;x++) {
        var i = (x + (y * (rowLength-1))) * 2;
        var biome = chunk.cells[x+','+y].biome;
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i] = [biomeTerrains[biome][0],biomeTerrains[biome][1],biomeTerrains[biome][3]];
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i+1] = [biomeTerrains[biome][1],biomeTerrains[biome][2],biomeTerrains[biome][3]];
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the resulting grey lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek6aX.png

I'd appreciate any ideas or advice on dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I slept on it, and the explanation came to me while showering. It's not an artifacting issue, the problem is that my UV coordinates are overshooting their intended space, so the lines are the result of the next texture in the atlas spilling over. I tested this theory by squeezing the UVs in by a small, arbitrary amount, and the lines disappeared. Unfortunately this isn't an ideal solution, but I should be able to figure out something more exact based on this knowledge.

Comment: After reading https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1433, I found a more reliable solution. When I load in my texture, I set the `minFilter` and `magFilter` to `THREE.LinearFilter`.